# Mysql query breaking when sent as GET parameter

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I am testing out a blind boolean SQL injection endpoint in a course and am having some issues figuring out where my payload is going wrong.

I have tested the below in the `mysql` shell on the target box and it works.

`GRANT/**/ALL/**/ON/**/*.*/**/TO/**/root@localhost;`

But when I submit it in the `q` `GET` param I am getting an error in the application.

`php?q=off')/**/or/**/GRANT/**/ALL/**/ON/**/*.*/**/TO/**/root@localhost%23`

I tested a basic boolean statement with `'1'='1'` instead and it works fine so I am assuming there is something wrong with my actual query in the context of the URL.

`q=off')/**/or/**/'1'='1'%23`

I have tried the payload url encoded as well but still with the same issues.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL injection to combine a partial expression like
`OR '1'='1'` as part of some other query works because there are many ways to append extra expression syntax to an existing SQL query that already has a WHERE clause.

For example, it's easy to see in the below example how the additional expression can be appended to the first query, and it's still a legal expression.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = 'off'
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = 'off' OR '1'='1' -- '
```

But GRANT is a statement on its own. It cannot be appended to another query like that. There's no way to combine GRANT with a SELECT statement.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = 'off' OR GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ...
```

That's just not a legal SQL query. You can study the [online syntax reference for SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) and other types of statements.

SQL injection works by tricking the app into executing one SQL statement with different syntax than the original intended SQL statement. But it can't make *invalid* syntax work!

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: Any reason that issue would apply to the below:

`?q=off'select/**/ascii((select/**/*/**/from/**/information_schema.user_privileges/**/where/**/'PRIVILEGE_TYPE'/**/=/**/'SUPER'/**/'GRANTEE'/**/=/**/user()))`

Comment: What is the result of combining your SQL injection content with the existing SQL query? Is that combination a valid SQL query?

Comment: I just pasted the wrong one. This is the  right one.

``?q=off')/**/or/**/select/**/ascii((SELECT/**/count(*)/**/grantee/**/FROM/**/information_schema.user_privileges/**/WHERE/**/privilege_type/**/=/**/'SUPER'/**/'grantee'=(select/**/user())))>0%23``

This is purely a SELECt so I thought it might work better than GRANT.

This still produces an application error though so I am assuming it's the same issue

Comment: What I was actually trying to achieve was a boolean query to determine if the current running user was a DBA or not

Comment: I understood that. My question stands: will the result of appending your SQL injection content result in a legal SQL query or not?

Comment: Tip: To use SQL injection effectively, you need to understand SQL syntax at least a little bit.

Comment: Fair point. I'll have to test it out more. It would seem not though. Back to the drawing board